# SQL Error on one server but not on the other despite the same code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called **comments** in MySQL -

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| data      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| createdOn | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I use CodeIgniter PHP framework. My PHP code that inserts a row in above table -

```
$comment = null;
if (isset($_POST['comment']) {
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
}
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
$input = array(
         'comment' => $comment,
         );
$data = json_encode($input);
$sql = "insert into comments(data, user_id) values ('$data', $user_id)";
log_message("info", "add sql :: $sql");
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Now the same code is deployed on two server.

- **server 1**
  PHP 5.3
  MySQL 5.5
- **server 2**
  PHP 5.4
  MySQL 5.5

When I give below input for a comment, it causes an SQL error -

```
hello'
```

Error -

```
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '321)' at line 1
insert into comments(data, user_id) values ('{"comment":"hello\\'"', 321)
Filename: /home/hussain/workspace/app/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/models/test_model.php
Line Number: 32
```

I get above error on server1 but not on server2. Why?

Comment: Why don't you use `CodeIgniter` build up `MySQL` functions to avoid SQL injections !

Comment: you are directly injecting your variables into the query, making the sql injection possible on either server.

Comment: 1 change `mysql*` to `mysqli` would help and change `isset()` to `empty()` would also help `empty()` will also check `isset()` third if you would add `strip_tags()` around your post would also help

Comment: Exactly what are you entering to get an injection?

Comment: @crypticous what are those?

Comment: @Jonathon I have updated the question with the input that causes the sql injection.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Comment: I think you don't need quotes around $data

Comment: @r3wt But the input `hello'` should make sql injection on both servers. It does on server1 but not on server2.

Comment: Are you sure what SQL Injection means? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 .

Comment: @Andrew yes I do need quotes around $data.

Comment: What exactly is happening that you believe is SQL injection?

Comment: Try `json_encode`ing your comment before `mysql_real_escape_string`ing it.

Comment: Perhaps `mysql_real_escape_string()` is doing nothing because you haven't specified a character set? Try calling `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` after setting up your database connection (replacing `'utf8'` with whatever character set you're actually using, of course).

Comment: @Jonathon you are right. Not able to simulate sql injection. I have updated the question

Comment: Perhaps magic quotes is turned off on one server and on on the other? http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: @Jonathon Yes. that might be the reason. how can I check that?

Comment: Use `phpinfo();` and look for the config setting for it.

Comment: I did `php phpinfo.php | grep magic`  . On server1 it says `hussain@magic-laptop:~/tmp$ php phpinfo.php | grep magic
magic_quotes_gpc => Off => Off
magic_quotes_runtime => Off => Off
magic_quotes_sybase => Off => Off` But on server2 it doesn't print anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.Escaping Queries Using below function**

- $this->db->escape_str()
- $this->db->escape()
- $this->db->escape_like_str()

  ```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (user_id,data) VALUES(".$this->db->escape($userid).",".$this->db->escape($userid).")";
  ```

**2.Query Bindings**

```
$comment =  $this->input->post('comment');
$row = array('user_id'=>$userid, 'data'=>$data);
$this->db->insert('comments', $row);
log_message('INFO', "SQL : " . $this->db->last_query());
```

You can log the last executed query using below statement and verify the injection

```
log_message('INFO', "SQL : " . $this->db->last_query());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `$comment = $this->input->post('comment');` to clean the input. then use

$data = array('user_id' => $userid, 'data' => $comment);

$this->db->insert('comments', $data);

to insert data into table.

Comment: my `data` is a json not a string. After I fetch it, I should be able to load it as json data.

Comment: even if post ```json``` data, you can get the value using ```$this->input->post('comment');``` then use, ```$comment_json = json_encode($comment);``` ```$data = array('user_id' => $userid, 'data' => $comment_json);``` finally use db->insert as above..